# How to export Google Ads reports to csv in Python? (getting AuthenticationError and HTTP Error 400)

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-ads-api

Connecting to ads api, configured yaml with credentials and testing out google's python example code but receiving above errors. How do I export simple keywords performance reports for all time to a csv?

Using Jupyter to test and run code on Python 3.6. I've used code from here: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/tree/master/examples/adwords/v201809/reporting

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

"""This example downloads a criteria performance report with AWQL.

To get report fields, run get_report_fields.py.

The LoadFromStorage method is pulling credentials and properties from a
"googleads.yaml" file. By default, it looks for this file in your home
directory. For more information, see the "Caching authentication information"
section of our README.

"""

import sys
from googleads import adwords


def main(client):
  # Initialize appropriate service.
  report_downloader = client.GetReportDownloader(version='v201809')

  # Create report query.
  report_query = (adwords.ReportQueryBuilder()
                  .Select('CampaignId', 'AdGroupId', 'Id', 'Criteria',
                          'CriteriaType', 'FinalUrls', 'Impressions', 'Clicks',
                          'Cost')
                  .From('CRITERIA_PERFORMANCE_REPORT')
                  .Where('Status').In('ENABLED', 'PAUSED')
                  .During('LAST_7_DAYS')
                  .Build())

  # You can provide a file object to write the output to. For this
  # demonstration we use sys.stdout to write the report to the screen.
  report_downloader.DownloadReportWithAwql(
      report_query, 'CSV', sys.stdout, skip_report_header=False,
      skip_column_header=False, skip_report_summary=False,
      include_zero_impressions=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  # Initialize client object.
  adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage()

  main(adwords_client)
```

alternatively used the following but getting the same errors:

```
# Using Pandas

from googleads import adwords
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

# Define output as a string
output = io.StringIO()

# Initialize appropriate service.
adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage()

report_downloader = adwords_client.GetReportDownloader(version='v201809')

# Create report query.
report_query = ('''
select Date, HourOfDay, Clicks
from ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
during LAST_7_DAYS''')

# Write query result to output file
report_downloader.DownloadReportWithAwql(
    report_query, 
    'CSV',
    output,
    client_customer_id='xxx-xxx-xxxx', # denotes which adw account to pull from
    skip_report_header=True, 
    skip_column_header=False,
    skip_report_summary=True, 
    include_zero_impressions=False)


output.seek(0)

df = pd.read_csv(output)

df.head()
```

Expecting some sort of output with the google ads report specified.

Comment: Following got me what I needed except only for a child account - would be great to have this for a parent/manager account: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47211319/how-to-pull-data-from-the-adwords-api-and-put-into-a-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

The `client_customer_id='xxx-xxx-xxxx'` was looking at the main account and not the client accounts, updated that and now works.